# Update(delete) values if row exist

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
(0)
PRIMARY(id) UNIQUE(account, type)
id | account | type | amount
1    1         1      3
2    2         2      2
3    1         2      1
```

So, (1) I need to decrease by 1 amount of one row and at the same time increase another; (2) if row we are increasing not exists, we create it with amount of one; (3) if amount in row we are decreasing is 1, we have to delete record; (4) if row we are decreasing not exists we do nothing.

Examples:

```
(0->1) Decrease id 2, increase id 3 result:
id | account | type | amount
1    1         1      3
2    2         2      1
3    1         2      2

(0->2) Decrease id 1, increase account 2 with type 1 result:
id | account | type | amount
1    1         1      2
2    2         2      2
3    1         2      1
4    2         1      1

(0->3) Decreasing id=3, increasing id=2 result:
id | account | type | amount
1    1         1      3
2    2         2      3

(0->4) Decreasing account 3 with type 1, increasing id=1 result:
id | account | type | amount
1    1         1      3
2    2         2      2
3    1         2      1

(extra) Decreasing id=3, increasing account 3 result:
id | account | type | amount
1    1         1      3
2    2         2      2
3    3         2      1
```

Id was used to point you faster, in real we focusing on pair account_type; so we are moving an unit of some type from one account to another;

How to implement this behavior in MySQL?

Comment: Look into `REPLACE INTO..` or  `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Start a transaction. Lock the rows. Then do what ever you need with the data. Then commit the transaction.